# Why can't I read multiple HDF5 files from a folder? Meanwhile, I can read a single HDF5 file fine... (Python 3.7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, glob, hdf5

I'm having trouble with some code to read multiple HDF5 files stored in a directory. I want to be able to read all of them in, then print one of the datasets stored in the HDF5 file. I have a folder full of identical HDF5 files (same 4 datasets, each dataset has the same shape) but they vary in their data (different values stored in each). Why am I experiencing an error while running this?

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import os

directory = '/Users/folder'

# for i in os.listdir(directory):
for i in directory:
#     if i.endswith('.h5'):
        with h5py.File(i, 'r') as data:
            extent = np.array(np.degrees(data['extent']))
        print(extent)
```

Here is the error from the first code snippet:

```
OSError: Unable to open file (file read failed: time = Thu May 14 12:46:54 2020
, filename = '/', file descriptor = 61, errno = 21, error message = 'Is a directory', buf = 0x7ffee42433b8, total read size = 8, bytes this sub-read = 8, bytes actually read = 18446744073709551615, offset = 0)
```

But I can run this just fine on a single HDF5 file...

```
file = 'file.h5'

data = h5py.File(file,'r')
extent = np.array(np.degrees(data['extent']))

print(extent)
```

And it outputs exactly what it should be:

```
[   1.   14.  180. -180.]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for i in directory` loops over the characters in the string.  So `['/', 'U', 's', ...]`.  The error is telling you that it opened `/` but it was a directory, not a file.  Your commented-out `os.listdir(directory)` is on the right track, but the yielded file names need to be appended to the base directory to make the full path.  You probably want

```
for i in os.listdir(directory):
    if i.endswith('.h5'):
        with h5py.File(os.path.join(directory, i)) as data:
            ...
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks - I now realize what I was doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `glob()` over `os.listdir()`. Why? Becuase you can use wildcards with the filename, and include the directory in the search (eliminates the need to concatenate the directory to the filename when you open the file).

- glob.glob() returns a list
- glob.iglob() returns an iterator (I prefer in this situation)

Example above redone with glob:

```
import glob
for h5f in glob.iglob(directory+'/*.h5'):
    with h5py.File(h5f) as data:
         ...
```